# anydesk cannot open ubuntu 22.04

Tags: anydesk

I got new installed 22.04 PC, after completing anydesk installation it work fine but when I click quit then open it again it won't open at all at least until I restart my PC, is there any reason why?

Comment: After you quit, have you checked in a terminal window to see if `anydesk` is still possibly running and not closing all the way?  `ps -ef | grep -i anydesk` or whatever its executable file is.

Comment: nothing other than the `grep` itself

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with Anydesk after I upgraded to 22.04 as well. After i disabled Wayland in the /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file by uncommenting this line "WaylandEnable=false" which switches it back to running Xorg instead of Wayland, it started working like normal

Comment: Doesn't commenting out `WaylandEnable=false` mean that `WaylandEnable` now has a value of `true` (meaning that you *enabled* Wayland?

Comment: UNcomment the line. The line is commented out by default.